# Passing normal data to pthread void *

Tags: c, pthreads

The pthread functions take a void * argument. How can a plain struct, not a pointer be sent in?

I want to send in a non pointer struct to one pthread function.

Also I want to send a pointer to the void * function, how is this done? can any pointer be sent in to the void * function?

Comment: To pass a struct, you need to pass the address of it (which converts it to a pointer).  However, you need to make sure that the object doesn't get destroyed (since the thread will have a reference to it).

Yes, you can pass any pointer to a void *

Comment: You can't (AFAIK).  What is wrong with a pointer to a heap-based struct?

Comment: Can I not just send the struct like this &thestruct to the (void *)

Comment: @Helium3: Yes, *but* make sure struct doesn't disappear.  So, if it was a local variable for example, the function may return in one thread, whilst the new thread still has a pointer to an object that no longer exists...

Comment: @forsvarir: If I have a struct to a GPSLocation. I have a watchdog thread starting and monitoring a GPS I/O thread and a GPS Navigation thread. I need to pass the struct to the watchdog, then pass it from the watchdog to the navigation thread.Will each thread function make a copy of it when it is casted back from a void * ? If a pointer is passed in, will this remove the possibility of bad data or the struct being lost/

Comment: @Helium3: No, casting back to a struct doesn't make a copy, the passed pointer is still refering to the original instance of the object.  It sounds like you need a malloc'd solution...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not possible; you have to send a pointer. However, a `void *` can point to anything. If your struct variable is called `foo`, you can simply pass it as `(void *) &foo`, and inside the function, you can cast it back into e.g. a `struct Foo` with `struct Foo * fooPtr = (struct Foo *) param;` or `struct Foo foo = *((struct Foo *) param);`.

Edit: As @forsvarir mentioned in the comment, `foo` *must not* be a local variable (unless the invoking function waits for the thread to complete). See @Gavin Lock's post.

Answer (score 7):

Based on your comments you need to do something like this...

In your main code:

```
void PassSomeStuff(struct TheStruct myStruct) {
    struct TheStruct *pStruct = malloc(sizeof(struct TheStruct));
    memcpy(pStruct, &myStruct, sizeof(struct TheStruct));

    /* Start the watchdog thread passing in the structure */
    pthread_create(/* other args */, &myWatchDogThreadFunc, pStruct); */
}
```

In your watchdog thread:

```
void *myWatchDogThreadFunc(void *pArgs) {
    struct TheStruct *pStruct = (struct TheStruct *)pArgs;

    /* use the struct */

    /* Pass Ownership to the navigation thread*/
    /* Start the navigation thread passing in the structure */
    pthread_create(/* other args */, &myNavigationThreadFunc, pStruct); 
}
```

In your navigation thread:

```
void *myNavigationThreadFunc(void *pArgs) {
    struct TheStruct *pStruct = (struct TheStruct *)pArgs;
    /* use the struct */

    /* cleanup */
    free(pStruct);  /* or pass it to somebody else... */
}
```

You can't just do:

```
void PassSomeStuff(struct TheStruct myStruct) {
    pthread_create(/* other args */, &myStruct);
}
```

Because `myStruct` will get cleaned up... when `PassSomeStuff` returns.  Taking the address (getting a pointer to it), doesn't copy the object.

Note:

- ANY of your threads can clean up the structure by calling free, as long as you're sure that ALL of the threads are finished with it.
- ALL of the threads (main, watchdog, navigation) are refering to the same instance of the structure (so if they're changing its contents you may need to protect it with locking).  If this isn't the desired effect, then you would need to create (malloc) a new copy of the structure at each step, so that each thread has it's own copy of the values.

Comment: I am going to pass a pointer from the start. malloc it before sending it into the watchdog(which is also a thread) and then the watchdog must pass it to a gps nav thread. Can I just pass the pointer along the void * pthread args then?

Comment: @Helium3: I've updated my post to reflect what I think you're saying, including some notes at the bottom.  The short answer is yes (assuming I've understood you correctly).

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, you have to pass a pointer. Think of void* as an untyped pointer, so you have to cast it back to the correct type inside your thread function. (see Aasmund's answer)

As forsvarir mentions, you HAVE to make sure that the pointed-to struct is not destroyed before the thread uses it - safest way to do this is to new the struct on the heap and pass its address and ownership to the thread function.

What I mean by "passing ownership" is that the function that news the struct **must not** delete it, and the thread function **must** delete the struct once it is done with it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, but rather an alternative solution to the warnings others have offered about making sure the structure still exists when the new thread gets it. Certainly you can use `malloc` to obtain it, and give the new thread the responsibility for `free`ing it. In many ways this seems like the simplest and cheapest way (no synchronization required), but the synchronization is actually hidden inside `malloc` and `free`, and could be mildly expensive, especially since most thread-oriented allocators (ptmalloc and tcmalloc for example) incur additional costs when the thread freeing the memory is not the same as the thread that allocated it.

An different approach you can use is to put a pthread barrier inside your init structure, and wait on it:

```
pthread_barrier_init(&init_struct.barrier, 0, 2);
pthread_create(&td, 0, start_func, &init_struct);
pthread_barrier_wait(&init_struct.barrier);
```

And have the thread start function also call `pthread_barrier_wait(arg->barrier);` after copying the struct to its own automatic storage.